# How to find GCD of n with integers smaller than n in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to find the GCD of the integers "n" with all the integers smaller than "n". For example, if n=6 ,I am finding the GCD of 6 and 1,2,3,4,5 . Here is my code to find GCD of 2 integers :

```
y=function(a,b){
m=min(a,b)
while(a%%m>0|b%%m>0){m=m-1}
return(m)}
```

I tried using the code below but it only show the first answer.

```
y=function(a){
m=a
for(i in 1:a){
while(a%%m>0|i%%m>0){m=m-1}
return(m)}
```

How can I modify my code to get the GCDs ? Thankyou in advance !!

Comment: what is your expected output for n = 6?

Comment: GCD of 6 and 1,2,3,4,5  which are 1,2,3,2,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't follow your attempt very well so I can not quickly pinpoint where it went wrong, but definitely you need to initiate a vector to store the results and append the results in each iteration of the loop.

The `names` bit is just for readability of results, not strictly necessary.

```r
get_gcd <- function(a, b) {
  m <- min(a,b)
  while(a %% m>0 | b %% m>0) {
    m <- m-1
  }
  return(m)
}

get_vec_of_gcd <- function(a) {
  # initiate vector for results 
  res <- rep(NA, length(a))
  for (i in 1:a) {
    res[i] <- get_gcd(a, i)
    # names just for better output interpretability 
    names(res)[i] <- paste(i, a, sep = ":")
  }
  res
}
get_vec_of_gcd(10)
#>  1:10  2:10  3:10  4:10  5:10  6:10  7:10  8:10  9:10 10:10 
#>     1     2     1     2     5     2     1     2     1    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: great. consider accepting the answer if it solves your question  (there is a check mark on the left, alongside the up and downvote buttons)